# css newly created div should go behind previous div

Tags: css, transform

Here, I am trying to create the browser tab.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og9kf4pu/)**

```
.intrnlTabs {
    background: #f0f1f3;
    height: 35px
}
.intrnlTab {
    background: #e7e9ec;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 12px
}
.intrnlTxt {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 150px;
    height: inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 10px
}
.intrnlCls {
    position: absolute;
    right: -23px;
    height: inherit;
    background: #dee1e5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    width: 33px;
    transform: skewX(30deg);
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center
}
.intrnlCls:hover {
    background: #d7d8d8
}
.intrnlClsicon {
    transform: skewX(-30deg);
    display: inline-block
}
```

**Output What I got**

[image]

**Output What I'm expect**

[image]

I want newly added tab header should go behind previous tab without adding z-index value. I have achieved it adding z-index value. But, I don't want to add z-index value.

Comment: `.intrnlCls { z-index:1; }` and done …

Comment: Can you explain why do don't want to use `z-index`? That will totally affect the range of possible answers.

Comment: @MrLister I guess they meant they don’t want to have to _calculate_ a specific z-index value based on element index or whatever, and aren’t aware this only needs a “static” one.

Comment: @MrLister Tabs are not static. it was dynamically created. So, I don't want to add z-index using scripts.

Comment: @04FS Yes. I'm not aware of this static code `z-index:1` will solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to calculate a *specific* z-index for each item, or assign it via JS to begin with.

Adding a z-index of 1 to these “X” items is enough already to achieve what you want:

```
.intrnlCls { z-index:1; }
```